# Change Div Content

Tags: html, jquery

I need help for my code to work. I know there are similar problem here but all the answer doesn't work on mine. So my problem is I want to change the content of Div by clicking one of my link. Here's my code.

```
        <div id="left">
             <h1>Welcome to This Section</h1>
             <h1>Welcome to This Content</h1>
        </div>
```

and Here is my link

```
           <div id="green2" class="block">
               <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
               <i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i>
           </div>
```

and this is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on('click', '.about', function(){
       document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = "<p>This is a <span>new</span> paragraph</p>";
   });

});
```

I just want to change everything in div with the id "left" but seems like there is something wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.about` selects a class, not an id (`#about` would select the id)

Comment: Hi, you need to learn to use the browser debugger or at least sprinkle your code with an abundance of `console.log`.  Why do I say this?  Your question concentrates on "change div content" and "change div with id left" - but this part of the code is fine.  The problem is the click handler - if you simply added a console.log before the doc.on.click and one after (before doc.getelement) then you'd see a) your code is running (a good start) and b) the click event never fires - so doesn't even get to the part you're asking about.  You could also have tried this part without the click handler.

Comment: @freedomn-m I might do some research about that, cause I'm new to jQuery :) Thank you btw.

Comment: From your comment to the answer that correctly answers your question *as presented* - can you update the question with what you've tried/not tried and what the exact problem is (and any console errors).   Your code, as presented (and assuming `#` as per comment) works fine and can easily be demonstrated to do so.

Comment: Ideally, you need to update your question to include a *snippet* that *demonstrates* the problem (see [mcve]).  In this case, here's a jsfiddle with your code (including `#` instead of `.`) that works fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/8m67a9ru/

Answer (score 1):

You wrong in js:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.about', function(){
```

is

```
 $(document).on('click', '#about', function(){
```

Because you catch the id not the class

Example without jquery(is not required):

```js
const about = document.getElementById("about");
about.onclick = function()   
{
   document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = "<p>This is a <span>new</span> paragraph</p>";
};
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <h1>Welcome to This Section</h1>
  <h1>Welcome to This Content</h1>
</div>
<div id="green2" class="block">
  <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
  <i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to change it back, I was just trying cause even i use #, the code still not running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery, why not using its functions? You are adressing .about instead of #about, also.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#about").on('click', function(){
       $("div#left").html("<p>This is a <span>new</span> paragraph</p>");
   });

});
```

Comment: You're missing a `.` before the `html()` function.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - it just converts to jquery with the same problem OP has and introduces multiple new issues, not least missing a `.`

Comment: @Youji I also did that code but it still not working.